# how can i get the "real" resolution of my device?

Tags: android

Yes, I know I can use `DisplayMetrics` but the problem is that on some devices the `widthPixels` member is a wrong value (at least i have such one phone). The resolution in `setting` page is 720*1280, but `widthPixels` is 600 and `heightPixels` in `DisplayMetrics` is 1067.

Additionally, I have tried [`getRealSize`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRealSize%28android.graphics.Point%29) and the returned value is correct. But eventually I found that **the "real" width of my phone is 640** (and I guess the height is also a different number).

Awesome! what's really going on here?

**Edit:**

here're some data
`widthPixels` in `DisplayMetrics` is 600. `density` is 1.6, `heightPixels` is 1067.

And i have tried all your methods, but all not working. I won't need to post my question here if I could find the correct answer so easily.  The device is HN3-U01, made in china

Comment: why will the area subtracted by `width`? 600 is device width in portrait

Comment: Check Bhanu's answer. Thats correct.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code..

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get device resolution



int width = 0;
int height = 0;
Point size = new Point();
WindowManager w = getWindowManager();

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13)
{
    w.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
    width = size.x;
    height = size.y;
}
else
{
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    width = display.getWidth();
    height = display.getHeight();
}
```

because getWidth() and getHeight() method deprecated after `API level 13`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
    private DisplayMetrics metrics;
    private int widthPixels;
private float scaleFactor;
private float widthDp;
    metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    int density= getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;

    widthPixels = metrics.widthPixels;

    scaleFactor = metrics.density;

    widthDp = widthPixels / scaleFactor;
```

Comment: yes, all the above answers are correct, but not on my device, see my edit.